# LDA with Python - input files

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I'm running the lda library in Python and I am running this example. Does anyone know the format of X, vocab and titles? I can't find the documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import lda
X = lda.datasets.load_reuters()
vocab = lda.datasets.load_reuters_vocab()
titles = lda.datasets.load_reuters_titles()
```

Answer (score 7):

X is a matrix where the rows are titles, and and columns are vocab. It is a bag of word representation of the title's text.

```
X
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

In the above matrix each row is a bag of word represtation of individual titles. Each column represents a specific word example.

```
vocab[:5]
Out[5]: ('church', 'pope', 'years', 'people', 'mother')
```

So, each row i, col j in the X matrix gives the frequency of specific word in the ith title.

```
titles[:1]
Out[11]: ('0 UK: Prince Charles spearheads British royal revolution. LONDON 1996-08-20',)
```

The title U: Prince Charles ... mentions the word church once, pope 0 times, years once, and so on.

```
In [13]: type(titles)
Out[13]: tuple

In [14]: type(vocab)
Out[14]: tuple

In [15]: type(X)
Out[15]: numpy.ndarray
```